# Adjacent cell changes value based on change event and condition in same row

Tags: excel, vba, events

I'm trying to get an adjacent cell on the same row to change value based on whether a desired range is either empty, or has at least one used cell.

If after the change event rng has at least one used cell, change adjacent cell value to ON.

Else, change adjacent cell value to OFF.

Basically ON when first value is entered in any cell in the range, stays ON while other values are added to the range, and OFF when the last cell's value has been deleted.

I can get it to ON, but when I delete the last used cell in the range, the value does not switch to OFF.

What am I missing?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim KeyCellsB, rng As Range

Set KeyCellsB = Range("A3:J3")
Set rng = Range(Cells(Target.Row, 1), Cells(Target.Row, 10))

If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCellsB, Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then
    If Not IsEmpty(rng) Then
        Cells(Target.Row, 12).Value = "ON"
    Else
        Cells(Target.Row, 12).Value = "OFF"
    End If
End If

End Sub
```

**Update**

Here is a impler version of the code, still not working. I need it to switch to off only after ALL cells in Range(Cells(Target.Row, 1), Cells(Target.Row, 3)) are empty

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim KeyCells As Range

Set KeyCells = Range("A3:J3")

If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then
    If Not IsEmpty(Range(Cells(Target.Row, 1), Cells(Target.Row, 3))) Then
        Cells(Target.Row, 12).Value = "ON"
    Else
        Cells(Target.Row, 12).Value = "OFF"
    End If
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Slightly confusing as to what you are trying to achieve. The code will fire only when  there is a change in `A3:J3`. On the other hand you are setting `rng` to target row which is `3` in this case? So it will never be empty...

Comment: When a user inputs a value in any cell in a horizontal range, another cell (not in the range) fires. I can achieve this. But what I also need is, if the user backtracks and empties all cells in the range, the other cell fires again. I In the cell that fires, I want to add a validation list. If a user inputs at least one value in any cell of the reference range, the validation code fires for the designated cell. And, if the user backtracks and empties *all* cells in the designated range, code deleting the validation for the designated cell fires and deletes the validation.